# Is the Enhanced Vegetation Index normalized?

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, evi, normalize

I am trying to figure out if the Enhanced Vegetation Index (2-band) is normalized or not? My first guess is that it is, but due to a multiplication factor of 2.4, I'm not sure if it is or not. The following paper describes the EVI2: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425708001971

The formula is as follows: 2.5((NIR - R)/(NIR + 2.4R + 1))

Is this an example of band normalization, such as how the NDVI index normalizes its data between -1 and 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EVI and NDVI range value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140696/evi-and-ndvi-range-value)

Comment: @Geraldine it touches on it, but doesn't outright answer my question. The NDVI is considered a "normalized" index; I'm trying to find out if it considered a "normalized" index or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVI2 is similar to NDVI in that it is a unitless continuous variable and the values range between -1 and 1:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X10001779

I'm not sure what you mean by normalized here. It's normalized in the sense that the EVI2 values are normalized on a scale of -1 to 1 on say two different images, but this is not an example of normalizing the reflectance of one sensor to another:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425715302455

Or say relative normalization where a time series of images are normalized to a master image:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425714003435