# Extracting NDVI and EVI in Alaska (EVI is showing -2 to 2 values)

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8, evi

I am working on extracting NDVI and EVI across the Landsat 8 collection in Alaska. Everything seems to be going swell, except the calculated EVI values are going from -2 to 2 instead of -1 to 1. I used the Landsat 8 surface reflectance equation for EVI that is listed on the USGS site for landsat indices and double checked it on some other peoples equations. I am wondering if there is something in my code that is off being that EVI values should range from -1 to 1 normally.

Code is linked here and EVI part is on line 132:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/976e426fae2842b9848886eea2c6c146
as follows.

```
function addEVI(img) {
  var evi = img.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': img.select('NIR'),
      'RED': img.select('Red'),
      'BLUE': img.select('Blue')
    }).rename('EVI');
  return img.addBands(evi);
}

// bring in collection and sites
var ptsLandsat = sites.map(bufferPoints(15, true));

var oliCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(ptsLandsat)
  .map(prepOli)
  .map(addNDVI)
  .map(addEVI);
  

var ndviParams = {bands: ['NDVI'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
  };
  
var eviParams = {bands: ['EVI'],
  min: -2.0,
  max: 2.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
  };
Map.addLayer(oliCol, ndviParams, 'NDVI');
Map.addLayer(oliCol, eviParams, 'EVI');
Map.addLayer(ptsLandsat)

// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsLandsatStats = zonalStats(oliCol, ptsLandsat, params);
print(ptsLandsatStats.limit(50));

// export table to drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ptsLandsatStats,
  folder: 'earthengine',
  description: 'test',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without access to you assets it is hard to determine if something goes wrong with your EVI calculations, your formula indeed is correct. Although EVI is known to go outside of the typical range (-1 to 1), see for example this answer: [EVI and NDVI range value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140696/evi-and-ndvi-range-value).

Answer (score 0):

EVI is not a normalized index like NDVI, so it does not follow this range rule (-1 to 1).