Why EVI values calculated from SkySat imagery in GEE are out of range?
I am using a SkySat imagery with 4 bands: B,G,R,NIR to calculate the EVI index in Google Earth Engine. I use this formula:
var evi =  SS_Area_N19_Trees.expression('2.5 * ((nir - red) / (nir + 6 * red - 7.5 * blue + 1))', {
    blue: SS_Area_N19_Trees.select('b1'),
    red:SS_Area_N19_Trees.select('b3'),
    nir: SS_Area_N19_Trees.select('b4') 
});


The values are more than 1 all over the map. How should I change the C1, C1 values to match the SkySat image?

EVI is not normalized and values >1 can appear https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140696/evi-and-ndvi-range-value. Maybe more than 1 all over the map is not normal, though.
